# How to sign Android Google Drive API App

Tags: android, google-api

I am developing a new Android app using Google Drive API. 
I use Android Studio 1.2.1. 
I have seen the //developers.google.com/drive/android/get-started. 
So I followed their instruction. 
I already have a Goolge Developer ID. But my app can't sign the Google Drive API. 
I have a ClientID and AndroidKey for Google Drive API. But I don't know how to configure the ID and Key to my APP.Can anyone help you. Thanks.

Comment: see the next page https://developers.google.com/drive/android/auth#connecting_and_authorizing_the_google_drive_android_api

Comment: thanks gabber. I have seen. I already added the code. But my app can't sign.

Comment: You can checkout the google-quick-start-app and try to change app keys "git clone https://github.com/googleplus/gplus-quickstart-android.git"

Comment: Hello. I have already used google-quick-start-app. I followed their instruction. But After the app is run, I can't sign the app using my gmail account. My gmail account is already registerd in Google Developer Account.

Comment: What error code do you have or some logs?